# Consulta @oneToMany para regresar un JSON con su respectiva lista de JSON

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jsonarray, jpql

tengo el siguiente problema y no eh podido resolverlo.
Estoy intentando regresar una lista de JSON que asu ves tiene un arrayList de objetos.

A continuación describo lo siguiente:

1)Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta join sobre la misma tabla el cual contiene los campos 
*ciudad
*nombre
*telefono
lo que necesito que me regrese en el VO es el sigueinte JSON sobre lo que tengo en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El JSON que necesito a partir de esta tabla es el sguiente:

> [{"ciudad":"o","nombtre":"a",[{"telefono":"i","telefono":"i"}],
>   {"ciudad":"o","nombtre":"o",[{"telefono":"i","telefono":"i"}],
>   {"ciudad":"a","nombtre":"a","telefono":a}]

**Actualmente lo que me regresa el objeto JSON es lo siguiente:**

> [{"ciudad":"o","nombtre":"a","telefono":null},
>   {"ciudad":"o","nombtre":"o","telefono":null},
>   {"ciudad":"a","nombtre":"a","telefono":null}]

**Mis Entidades son la siguientes:**

```
@Entity
        @Table(name = "contact")
        public class CiudadEntity {
            @Id
            @Column(name = "city")
            private String ciudad;
            @Column(name = "firstname")
            private String nombre;

            @OneToMany
            private Set<TelefonoEntity> telefono;
        }



@Entity
    @Table(name = "contact")
    public class TelefonoEntity {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "city")
        private String ciudad;

        @Column(name = "telephone")
        private String telefono;
   }


 @Repository
    public interface CiudadRepository extends JpaRepository<CiudadEntity, String> {

        @Query("SELECT DISTINCT new com.mx.demo.vo.CiudadVO(a.ciudad, a.nombre, a.telefono.telefono) FROM CiudadEntity a  JOIN TelefonoEntity b ON a.ciudad = b.ciudad")
        public List<CiudadVO> obtenerCiudad();

    }
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como mandar una lista de telefonos a travez de mi VO. Les dejo las clases VO.

Clase CiudadVO

```
    public CiudadVO(String ciudad, String nombtre, Set<TelefonoVO> telefono) {
            this.ciudad = ciudad;
            this.nombtre = nombtre;
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }

}

public TelefonoVO(String telefono) {
    super();
    this.telefono = telefono;
}
```

Si yo mando solamente mi consulta solamente con ciudad y nombre si me regresa un valor el JSON pero al querer ya mandar tambien la lista de telefonos simplemente me arroja el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for
>   query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.mx.demo.repository.CiudadRepository.obtenerCiudad()! Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
>   illegal attempt to dereference collection [ciudadenti0_.city.telefono]
>   with element property reference [telefono] [SELECT DISTINCT new
>   com.mx.demo.vo.CiudadVO(a.ciudad, a.nombre, a.telefono.telefono) FROM
>   com.mx.demo.entity.CiudadEntity a  JOIN
>   com.mx.demo.entity.TelefonoEntity b ON a.ciudad = b.ciudad] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference
>   collection [ciudadenti0_.city.telefono] with element property
>   reference [telefono] [SELECT DISTINCT new
>   com.mx.demo.vo.CiudadVO(a.ciudad, a.nombre, a.telefono.telefono) FROM
>   com.mx.demo.entity.CiudadEntity a  JOIN
>   com.mx.demo.entity.TelefonoEntity b ON a.ciudad = b.ciudad] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference
>   collection [ciudadenti0_.city.telefono] with element property
>   reference [telefono]

Comment: La excepción viene porque estás usando en el query a.telefono.telefono, pero a.telefono es un Set, que no tiene un atributo telefono.

Comment: Y como podria pasar el set para llegar al resultado del JSON. Gracias